# ModelSerializer In Django Rest is not recognizing model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a Rest Model Serializer but the Django is not recognizing my model serializer. I can't determine what the issue is. Here is my code:
Help would be appreciated since my other models seem to be working.

Serializer:

```
class BackgroundScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = SavedSchedules
    exclude = ("_created__")
```

Model:

```
class SavedSchedules(models.Model):
fromDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
toDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
summary = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Output from Python. As you can see, the meta-data is not printed. [Note I did not crop the data at the bottom. There was nothing printed]
[[image: This is output from the Django-REST Interpreter]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB0Us.png)

Comment: Include the code as text, not images.

Comment: there's a squiggly line making it hard to read what's on the line `exclude = ...` Is it `exclude = ('_created__')` ? What are the parentheses and the underscores for? Is it supposed to be `exclude = ('created',)` ? The comma is required in a single item tuple. If there's no comma the parenthesis will be parsed as a grouping operator.